# Image getting dark

Tags: python, image, image-processing, gaussian, noise-generator

I did a program in python to apply Gaussian noise on an image as follows.
Input image is :

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
from math import *

import numpy

list1 = []
list2 = []

im = Image.open("313.JPG")
im.show()
list1 = list(im.getdata())

length = len(list1)
total = 0
for i in list1:
    total = total + i
mean = total /length  #mean
sd = numpy.std(list1) #standard deviation
print "mean is %d" %(mean)
print "sd is %d" %(sd)
for i in list1:
    g = (1/(sd * sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(-((i - mean)**2)/(2*(sd**2)))) #gaussian 
    list2.append(g)
im.putdata(list2)
im.save('q4.jpg')             
im.show()
```

But I am getting a complete dark image instead of getting noise on image.Please help.I'm expecting the below image as output.
[image]

Comment: I get an error in running it. In fact in the first loop, `i` is a tuple (or size 3), how could you add it to total? (I have python2.7)

Comment: i is intensity value in each pixel position.It is an item in list1.not a tuple and all.Summing up each i we get total

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.5

Comment: Ok, BTW, Are you sure that your gaussian isn't normalized? I mean, you should send an list of integers to list2. I fear `g` is always `0` as integer. Maybe you should multiply `g` for some contant..like `255`.

Comment: No.Please print the list1 and 2.list 2 value is near to 0.Thats the problem.

Comment: Isn't this near to what I said in my last comment?

Comment: Yes.But my program is executing error free.Problem is with incorrect output

Comment: Don't you want to use something like `numpy.random.normal` to generate the random data? You code is basically finding how many standard deviations away from the mean each pixel is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from math import *
import numpy

list1 = []
im = Image.open("313.JPG")
im.show()
list1 = list(im.getdata())
length = len(list1)

# generate random noise data with mean 0 and sd 10
list2 = numpy.random.normal(0, 10, length)
# Add this to the image data
list3 = list1+list2

im.putdata(list3)
im.show()
```

[image: Result of adding noise]

Answer (score 1):

Since gaussian is normalized, and its peak is in `1/sqrt(2pi)`, you should multiply `g` for `255*sqrt(2*math.pi)`.

Since yout `g` is not a normal gaussian, but it is also normalized by `1/sd`, to let `g` span fro m`0` to `255` you shoud moltiply `g` by `N` as follows:

```
N = 255.*sqrt(2.*pi)*sd
g = N*(1/(sd * sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(-((i - mean)**2)/(2*(sd**2))))
```

This is what I get with your image as input:

[image]

It is correct: your algorithm just compute for every pixel, its gaussian value (where the gaussian is centered in the mean value): this means that pixel with a value near the average value will get brigher and pixel distant from the average get darker. No way to get a noise from that. You should re think your algorithm.

Comment: Same output is getting-dark image

Comment: what are the values of `g` now?

Comment: nearly to zero.Please print list 2

Comment: If it works, then set my answer as "accepted" by clicking in the "V" symbol in the left.

Comment: Ok.But output is not the required one.I'm getting a gray image now.not a noisy one

Comment: Explain in which way you hope to do this.

Comment: image with white grains(noise)

Comment: I think you should add some random process then.

Comment: Updated the image in question.Please check

Comment: What is your input image? this is what I obtain if I put your profile picture as input: http://i.imgur.com/ui5fhuU.png